# How to kill all processes started with subprocess.run(python pyscript1.py & python pyscript2.py & python3 pyscript3.py )

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running a python3 script to track object with tensorflow and webcam. The script outputs the coordinates constantly to memcache. I use two seperate scripts to turn the cameras x axis and y axis because I will try different types of motors and drives for different axis. All is well and works if I start everything separately.

Now I'm trying to run all the scripts simultaneusly with subprocess.run() command. In case of error I would like to have all those processed killed and run "stopmotors.py" script.

```
import subprocess
try:
   trackign = subprocess.run("python3 ~/tflite1/TFLite_detection_webcam_cmd.py --modeldir ~/tflite1/Sample_TFLite_model/ --edgetpu & python ~/motorhat/Stepper_Motor_HAT_Code/python/xdrive.py & python ~/motorhat/Stepper_Motor_HAT_Code/python/ydrive.py", shell=True)
```

I have also tried different ways to do the following:

```
except:
    tracking.kill()
    subprocess.run("python ~/motorhat/stopmotors.py")
    exit()
```

Currently I'm unable to kill and exit the program loop.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use ``subprocess.run``? This will block until the process is done. Managing the lifetime of *several* subprocesses is much easier with ``subprocess.Popen``.